# This, that, these, those

Tags: style, academic-writing, book, grammar

English is not my first language. I am writing a more or less formal text (nonfiction).

When I am talking about something that I introduced in a previous paragraph or sentence, is it correct to *always* use **this**, or should I use **that**?

I am not sure when to use **this** and when to use **that**, when talking about something that I just mentioned.

Comment: See [Using "that" and "this" interchangeably](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/4325/191178) on our sister site.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer without information to go off of. Try adding more and maybe an answer will be easier to come across.

Comment: There are no hard and fast rules, and often either is possible. If you have specific sentences/paragraphs you could raise them on English Language Learners or English Language and Usage, which are better places for English grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is complex, so complex that even native speakers are not 100% sure about when to use **this** and when to use **that**. This answer (with its comments) is not perfect, but helps:

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/4330/442937

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community Bot, it's fine. Sure it's short, but it's useful!